# Refresh using UIRefreshControl depending on current URL

Tags: ios, webview, uirefreshcontrol

I have recently dropped iOS 5 support for my app and went with using UIRefreshControl. I't all set up and working perfectly. My goal from this thread is to have it refresh if its a current url in my website, or if it's on another site like youtube, have it reload and refresh back to my site. Make sense?

So far I have tried doing this without success. I went to YouTube, and the NSLog showed it as my current site. Which I am confused about as it's clearly not.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
-(void)handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh {

    NSString *string = @"MySite.com";
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"MySite"].location == NSNotFound) {

        // Reload my data
        NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.MySite.com/";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

        [(UIWebView *)[self.view viewWithTag:999] reload];
        [overlay postMessage:@"Reloading" duration:1 animated:YES];

        //set the title while refreshing
        refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Refreshing the View"];
        //set the date and time of refreshing
        NSDateFormatter *formattedDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formattedDate setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:mm a"];
        NSString *lastupdated = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last Updated on %@",[formattedDate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
        refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:lastupdated];
        lastupdated:[UIColor colorWithRed:(87.0/255.0) green:(108.0/255.0) blue:(137.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

        //end the refreshing
        [refresh endRefreshing];
        NSLog(@"String does not contain MySite");

    } else {

        // Reload my data
        NSString *fullURL = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

        [(UIWebView *)[self.view viewWithTag:999] reload];
        [overlay postMessage:@"Reloading" duration:1 animated:YES];

        //set the title while refreshing
        refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Refreshing the View"];
        //set the date and time of refreshing
        NSDateFormatter *formattedDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formattedDate setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:mm a"];
        NSString *lastupdate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last Updated on %@",[formattedDate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
        refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:lastupdate];
        lastupdate:[UIColor colorWithRed:(87.0/255.0) green:(108.0/255.0) blue:(137.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

        //end the refreshing
        [refresh endRefreshing];
        NSLog(@"String contains MySite");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it.

Literally had to change the top: NSString *string = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;

So far so good. If I have any other issues with it ill bump this thread.